# Adding a Push Notification red bubble on the Icon

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to have a similar functionality as shown in the [image](http://www.iphoneincanada.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/push_02.jpg). I will have a `UITabBarController` and on the first view i have a `TableView`. Data populated to this table view will come from a remote server.

When my application is idle or when it is inactive and when there is a new set of data coming from the server, I need to display the number of new records in that "Red bubble" as shown in the image.

Comment: umm. have you read the Apple Push Notification Guide at all? it's basically all there. and there are great tutorials all over the internet for both the client and server side.

Comment: It will be easier for you if you search for "badge" instead of "red bubble". There are many similar questions around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to show badge number on the application icon, use the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
```

it will display 1 on the application icon.

Comment: +1 Much more useful than "RTFM" comments.   The sheer bulk of the docs can be overwhelming sometimes.    What would SO be with nothing but RTFM answers?   I bet 99% of questions could be answered by sitting down for a month or two [yes hyperbole but you know what I mean] with written docs and slogging it out.